# Django Tastypie - using slug IN ADDITION to Id

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to use both a slug and id to access my resources, so that the following urls would both point to the same resource

```
http://site.com/api/resource/this-is-the-slug
http://site.com/api/resource/35
```

I have added the following to my resource

```
prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<slug>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
    ]
```

Which gets the slug url working fine but unfortunately breaks the id url.
How do I get both of them working together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have 2 targets for the same view
Also, slugs never have `.` and `_`

```
prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<id>[\d]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),

    ]
```

Comment: I tried that already but it doesn't work for me.
When I try using the id I get a 404 - I assume because the first url is taking the id and using it as a slug.

Comment: Ah - but it does work if I reverse the order of the urls...
No idea why I didn't spot this earlier, thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh  its because it matches the first case and does not find a slug by that id  hence the 404  I should have caught it